# WebAudio: how does timeConstant in setTargetAtTime work?

Tags: html, web-audio-api

I want to rapidly fade out an oscillator in order to remove the pop/hiss I get from simply stoping it. Chris Wilson proposed the [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16115355/731172) to set [setTargetAtTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#dfn-setTargetAtTime) on the gain.

Now I don't quite grasp its last parameter 'timeConstant':

What's its unit? Seconds?
What do I have to put in there to get to the target-value in 1ms?

Answer (score 10):

That Chris Wilson guy, such a trouble.  :)

setTargetAtTime is an exponential falloff.  The parameter is a time constant:

"timeConstant is the time it takes a first-order linear continuous time-invariant system to reach the value 1 - 1/e (around 63.2%) given a step input response (transition from 0 to 1 value)."

So, for every "timeconstant" length of time, the level will drop by a bit over 2/3rds (presuming the gain was 1, and you're setting a target of 0.  At some point, the falloff becomes so close to zero, it's below the noise threshold, and you don't need to worry about this.  It won't ever "get to the target value" - it successively approximates it, although of course at some point the difference falls below the precision you can represent in a float.

I'd suggest experimenting a bit, but here's a quick guess to get you started:

```
// only setting this up as a var to multiply it later - you can hardcode.
// initial value is 1 millisecond - experiment with this value if it's not fading
// quickly enough.
var timeConstant = 0.001; 

gain = ctx.createGain();
// connect up the node in place here
gain.gain.setTargetAtTime(0, ctx.currentTime, timeConstant);

// by my quick math, 8x TC should take you to around 2.5% of the original level 
// - more than enough to smooth the envelope off.
myBufferSourceNode.stop( ctx.currentTime + (8 * timeConstant) );
```

Comment: timeConstant is very unintuitive for me, coming from css-transitions where you control the duration of a transition. I understand that zero will never get reached. A friend suggested the pragmatical approach to multiply the exponential function with a very slowly decreasing linear function – like y = 1-(x/10000) – to eventually get a zero-crossing.

Comment: You can use linearRampToValueAtTime or exponentialRampToValueAtTime, too - those do have endpoints, like I think you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your post which made it clear to me how the setTargetAtTime works, but.. I want to create an enveloppe with an exponential decay from 1 to 0.1 for 500ms, and then a linear release from 0.1 to 0 for 500ms. As far as I understand, there is no way to tell the API to proceed the linear ramp from the value after the decay to 0. Do I need to manually compute the expected value, call setValueAtTime(500ms, computed value) and then call linearRampToValue ? I apologyse for being off topic from the main question. thanks for feedback.

Comment: No,you should in this case be able to set the initial value (setValueAtTime) to 1 at time t, then use exponentialRampToValueAtTime( 0.1, t+0.5), then linearRampToValueAtTime( 0, t+1.0);

Comment: @cwilso I am sure there is a good reason for this, that I am not aware of, but why isn't there just a duration param, so you know exactly how long would it take for setTargetAtTime to finish?

Comment: Because setTargetAtTime doesn't ever "finish" - it just continues to approach the value, until the delta passes below the precision of a floating point value.  exponentialRampToValueAtTime finishes - at its assigned time - but setTargetAtTime just says "keep approaching this value".

Answer (score 1):

though I realize this might not be technically correct ( given the exponential nature of the time constant ) but i've been using this formula to "convert" from seconds to "time constant"

```
function secondsToTimeConstant( sec ){
    return ( sec * 2 ) / 10;
}
```

...this was just via trial and error, but it more or less has been working out for me

Comment: @cwilso am I overlooking something that might screw things up in ways I've haven't anticipated? or ( as been my experience so far ) will this work good enough?